# jQuery UI included, not understanding why it is failing

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

http://churchsafeplan.com/overview.php?content=0201#intro

For some strange, strange reason, the function "accordian" is not working.  Seems as if accordian does not exist, though the jQuery UI file is being called.  It doesn't make sense to me, and it feels like I am wasting time so if anyone could help, it would be MUCH appreciated.

The javascript is on the bottom btw.

Figured out the problem was actually a typo.  Normally jQuery doesn't break when the HTML doesn't fit, but in this case it was breaking because the HTML didn't fit.  Which I think is rather weird.

Comment: Hope its not a typo `accordian > accordion`?

Comment: should this line : `//$("#accordion").accordion();` be commented?

Comment: Also, this is commented `//$("#accordion").accordion();`. In your case, should be `$("#accordian").accordion();`

Comment: Oh no I commented it out because it was breaking.

Comment: @Luke - instead of editing the question title, choose an answer and click the big tick to the left.

Comment: Adam, it won't let me for another 2 minutes.  I am letting people know right now that there is no need for further help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is it not working? What is the expected behavior? I just see a long form.  When I put your commented out accordion code `$("#accordion").accordion();` into the javascript console, it runs but matches nothing. More info would be helpful.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because you were the only one not to criticize me for commenting out the code to make it stop breaking the rest of the website.

Comment: @Luke - Stack Overflow is not only a great place for asking questions - it's a great place for researching problems. The question marked as correct should be the one that is most useful, both to you and anyone else who has the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery UI is being downloaded - I can see it in Firebug.

I can also see that your accordion call is commented out:

```
//$("#accordion").accordion();
```

Plus, no elements match the selector `#accordion`, I think you mean `#accordian`.

Fix the typo and uncomment the line and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Install Firebug, a script debugging extension for Firefox. Use it to see where the issues are popping up. It also includes a console window that will let you see if objects are defined or not at a certain point in your code.

http://www.getfirebug.com

Answer (score 0):

You have commented out the accordion initialization

```
//$("#accordion").accordion();
```